# OpenCV JS, get black text from image

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I need to get only text(levels in rectangles above circles) from image without any junk but with minimal data loss...this is as far as i can get...is there any way to get better results?
EDIT for OpenCV tag: I`m using latest OpenCV(i guess official documentation page is running on latest version)
[image]

[There is some images to test with](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PmFpcdXs3f_8T8k5fnbAgU81s1RePrDB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: is the text you're looking for always going to be these numbers?

Comment: Honestly, I would probably go with something like neural network text extraction: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/

Comment: @Zock77 does OpenCV.js have something like EAST?

Comment: @IanChu yes, always these numbers